# Nested parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I know how to use

```
${parameter#word} Remove matching prefix pattern
```

and

```
${parameter%word} Remove matching suffix pattern.
```

but is there a way to nest them in a single call, such as

```
${${variable#foo}%bar}
```

?

It looks like I should be able to use this somehow

> If the first character of parameter is  an  exclamation  point  (!),  a level  of  variable  indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter  itself.

but I can't figure  it out.

Comment: You can't combine indirection with removals. In indirection, there are two variables involved, one containing the name of the other. In removals, there are two strings involved, but only one variable.